# A delegate in C# to VB.NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, nunit

I'm trying to convert this working .NET2 C# into .NET2 VB.NET, using NUnit 2.6.4

```
[Test]
public void Test() {
    Assert.Throws<Exception>(delegate {
        DoSomething(2);
    });
}

public void DoSomething(int i) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

then into VB:

```
<Test> _
Public Sub Test()
    Assert.Throws(Of Exception)(Sub() DoSomething(2))
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething(i As Integer)
    Throw New Exception()
End Sub
```

this works in .NET4 but not .NET2 - as I'm using an anonymous method... but how to express a delegate in .NET2 in VB.NET

Something like: `AddressOf DoSomething(2)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new named method, rather than using an anonymous method.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Assert.Throws(Of Exception)(AddressOf DoSomethingPassingTwo)
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomethingPassingTwo()
    DoSomething(2)
End Sub

Public Sub DoSomething(i As Integer)
    Throw New Exception()
End Sub
```